# If there is an open set containing a point $p$, is there an open ball containing $p$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am starting to study differential geometry, with Pressley's "Elementary Differential Geometry".

An important notion is that of an open set. My question is that, if there exists an open set $U$ containing a point $\mathbf{p}$, then is it necessarily the case that there exists an open ball containing $\mathbf{p}$?

Here is Pressley's definition of an open set:

> A subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called open if, whenever $\mathbf{a} \in U$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. every point $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ within a distance $\epsilon$ of $\mathbf{a}$ is also in $U$:
> $$
> \mathbf{a} \in U \text{ and } ||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{a} || < \epsilon \implies \mathbf{u} \in U
> $$

I ask this because visualizing a lot of the definitions and theorems becomes much easier when I am imagining the intersection of a set and an open ball, rather than a set and some arbitrary open set.

For example, the definition of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ becomes much more understandable to me when phrased in terms of open balls. It is as follows:

> A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a surface if, for every point $\mathbf{p} \in S$, there is an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and an open set $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing $\mathbb{p}$, such that $S \cap W$ is homeomorphic to $U$.

I'm asking my question since, ultimately, I want to know if it is justified to replace instances of "open set" with "open ball" (of course, keeping the respective dimensions in mind) in these definitions, since that is more understandable to me.

Comment: How do you define open set?

Comment: I have updated the post with Pressley's definition precisely as it is in the textbook, although I think it is a bit poorly written.

Comment: That's the definition of surface, not the definition of open set.

Comment: Both of the definitions are in the post.

Comment: You are right. But the, by that definition of open set, a set $U$ is open if and only if, for each $u\in U$, there is an open ball centered at $u$ contained in $U$. I suppose that this answers your question.

Comment: **such that every point $a\in U$ within a distance of $\epsilon$ (so basically $\epsilon$ is the radius) is also in $U$**